# Does a Certificate Authority represent my company or a server?

Tags: security, openvpn, certificates

I am setting up my second OpenVPN server with TLS and so I have a question about CA. Should I create a separate CA for each server or use the same?

Why?

Both servers will cater to the same network of clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same CA and make sure it's secured (as anyone compromising it would be able to issue certificates for it and perform a MITM attack).  You might consider putting a machine offline and using it for this purpose only.

As long as it's for internal use only, a self-signed cert will work fine.  Remember that you'll have to install the CA root cert on all clients.

Edit: as for the question in the title, a CA never represents a single server. It represents a company, or a department. (Here "represents" is used in the meaning of "is able to deliver certificates to").

Answer (score 0):

Your question scares me. Generally speaking you don't create a CA for VPN services.

You request a CA sign a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) in order to perform a repudiation for the TLS protocol which your trying to implement.

I believe what your really asking is about a x.509 certificate, or specifically 'Should I create a separate x.509 certificate for each server or use the same?'

If I am correct and this is what you're asking, you may want to look into a 'wildcard certificate' type. This type will allow you to create and have signed by a CA (certificate authority) only one x.509 certificate you can use on multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks for the honest answer. To help you understand better, I am as a beginner following official Debian documentation: https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN which at one point sets up a "ca".

Comment: Being a beginner is something we all go through.

I do find it strange that would be included in official documentation as that would negate the purpose of TLS certificate validation and also force an organization to publish its own set of certificate chains (including root certificates) for proper client validation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting up a private CA for a VPN if it is not for public use (e.g. corporate VPN where only corp. users will connect with the appropriate CA certs pre-loaded).

Comment: Which is possible, but negates the OSCP stapling functionality for validation of x.509 certificates with which the TLS protocol is designed.

Answer (score -1):

CA is an authority. No more, no less.
This is not absolutely linked to server.

CA is - to a certain extent - the very big boss.
CA (is above)> server(s) > client(s).

In addition, if your clients can connect 2 servers, no exclusions and so on, use a only one CA. That's perfectly normal.

Comment: I would like to know why - 1... CA is the space of unicity for your clients...